# Move directories less than 1G

Tags: linux, shell, xargs, mv, du

I am trying to move all directories less than 1GB. I am trying to use this command:

```
du -h -d 1 -t -1G | xargs -0 mv -it /destination/dir/
```

But I get an error message:

```
mv: cannot stat [...] File name too long
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: try adding `-L 1` to xargs: `du -h -d 1 -t -1G | xargs -0 -L 1 mv -it /destination/dir/`

Comment: Thanks :) I tried with `-L 1`but that generates the following error message, `mv: cannot stat ‘du -h -d 1 -t -1G\n’: No such file or directory` I also tried with `-n1`but that also gave me an error message `mv: invalid option -- 'h'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a workaround that serves my needs. Perhaps somebody can expand on it? Anyway, IF you don't need to worry about sub directories then the following works.

```
du -Sb -t -1G | cut -f 2- | xargs -d "\n" mv -t /path/to/destination/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using the `-0` argument to `xargs` as this specifies that the filenames are separated by null bytes rather than spaces. The output of `du` won't contain any null bytes so the entire output will be treated as a single filename, causing the error that you're seeing.

Anyway, I would suggest using `find`:

```
find /path/to/source -type d -size -1024M -exec mv -it /path/to/destination {} +
```

If you're happy that `du` is already producing the output that you want and want to use it instead, you can add the `-0` switch so that it uses null byte separators, then your current `xargs` command should work.

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately I am completely unable to get `find`to bend to my will. If I just run everything before `-exec` to check the output, it seems to ignore the `-type d` flag and simply output every file less than 1024M.

Comment: Maybe you can just add the `-0` switch to `du` (see my update).

Comment: Now we're getting really close! Only problem is that `du` is outputting the dir sizes which gets piped to `mv` and obviously `mv` no longer recognizes the dir names.

Comment: Yeah, the output of your command didn't look right on my system either, which was why I suggested using `find` in the first place. I'm not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: This led me to belive that I might be able to use `sed` to remove the numbers, eg: `du -d 1 -t -1G -0 | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | xargs -0 mv -it /destination/` Unfortunately this produced another error: `mv: cannot stat ‘\t./Crank’: No such file or directory` Anyway, I would really love to get `find` to work but I'm having even less luck with that for some reason.